# Microsoft Access with SQL Server linked tables hangs when doing search using the On Change event

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I wonder if anyone has any advice for me, essentially we're using a textbox to do a search but it's causing some problems.  We have a listbox with rowsource set to the equivalent of
select * from tblSearch where searchField Like "*" & [Forms]![frmNames]![txtSearch].[Text] & "*"

This query has Max Rows set to 25 and all the tables are linked tables to SQL Server.  On the On Change event of the search textbox it runs a requery on the listbox and everything seems to be working sweet as a nut, except the database is hanging for users every day or so which is driving me nuts!

Having looked into this essentially what I've boiled it down to is that Access is sending the select statements to SQL (on the same server) but not waiting for each query to complete and processing it before moving on.  So before Access gets the response back from the server the user types the next character and it fires a new query to SQL.  In SQL Server then you find hung queries with resource wait "ASYNC_NETWORK_IO" which I understand is the client not consuming the data from SQL Server.

What I've had to do is change the event being used to requery from On Change to afterupdate which really takes away from the whole user experience of having a sort or "Google Instant" search experience as they have to type and hit Enter before seeing results, not nice!

So that's the issue, just wondering if anyone has any suggestions, I've run out of ideas now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The idea here is to keep the query results lean and mean.**  Every time this query runs in Access, which will easily be hundreds if not thousands of times (with an `OnChange` event and more than 1 user), you want as little coming through the pipes as possible. There's a number of optimizations you can perform to make the SQL query and its results faster:

1. Change `SELECT * FROM ...` to `SELECT [column1],[column2],[etc] FROM ...` (where the columns are only those columns needed for the ListBox.  Even if the table you're querying only has the columns you need, this is still best practice in that it is clear when you look at it again 3-12 months later and it saves the db engine (in either Access or SQL) from having to lookup the columns in the table.
2. Make sure you have an index on the `searchField` column in your SQL Server database.
3. Move the query to a view in SQL Server and put the `SELECT TOP 25...` there.  Even if you put the MAX ROWS 25 in Access, it could still pull more (ie ALL) and then filter to 25.  Also, by putting it in a view, you can put `WITH (NOLOCK)` at the end of the table (name/alias) giving SQL Server the hint that it doesn't need to lock anything on the table for this query.  This speeds things up especially if there are multiple users requerying frequently.

There are other things depending on your specific situation, but these will *definitely* reduce your hang time.

Comment: I'm only 4 years late for marking yours as the answer sorry!!  I made another plan in waiting though but completely forgot giving you some credit for good thoughts thanks.